# Rails pass has many through to a action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

On has many through select option

1. box has many colors through => colorship
2. color has many boxes through => colorship

---

```
def show
  Box.find(params[:id])
  @colors_for_dropdown = @box.colors.collect { |co| [co.name, co.id] }
end

<%= select_tag :color_id, 
options_for_select(@colors_for_dropdown.unshift(['Select Color', nil])) %>
```

I tried  to add the color of the box that the user choose on the basket.

but is showing all the colors, not what i choose. Someone have any tip or idea what is wrong?

```
  def add
    box = Box.find(params[:id])
    if box
      current_user.basket = Basket.new
      color = box.colorship.first.color.name
      current_user.basket.find_by_box_id_and_color_id(box.id, nil,
                                                      color.nil? ? nil : color.id)
    end
  end
```

Comment: please show the error

Comment: @jamesjaya, thank's i already added the error

Comment: change `color = box.colorship.first.color.name` to `color = box.colorship.first.color`

Comment: @jamesjaya thank's but on the basket still show all the colors

Comment: i'm just would like to pick a color. and show in the basket

Comment: Hey jjplack did you mean `through`? or it is `thought`?

Comment: @illusionist though